'make' command not working on my Raspberry Pi while compiling the SocketCAN driver
Problem: When running "make" command I am met with errors
I've been trying to install a SocketCAN driver on my pi device so I can communicate with a USB CAN Adapter. I've been following Systecs manuals for downloading/installing said software. Link to Systec Website and reading their Manual for Windows/Linux devices. When I downloaded the SocketCAN driver and followed the instructions and used the the make command on the pi device I get the error:
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build M=/home/pi/systec_can-v1.0.7 modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:22: all] Error 2

I tried this on ubuntu and it works fine. (Although the instructions are on a Ubuntu system so this makes sense) It does not work on the pi however. I was wondering any solutions for this problem, or if anyone else has run into this.

Have you checked if /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build/ exists?  It doesn't by default.

@goldilocks just checked, it did not exist, do I just create the dir manually?

Yes, make sure it ends up with appropriate permissions/ownership.

I also ran the command: sudo apt-get install
-reinstall raspberrypi-kernel-headers and the build folder appeared. I assume if I made a build folder manually the same would happen, thanks for the help. @goldilocks
